# a sample getJSON code is working well with jQuery 1.4.1.js but it not with jQuery 1.6.4 or above versions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, getjson

I am new to mobile application development and I have developed a piece of code with the `getJSON` method that works very well with jQuery 1.4.1.js version.

However, this js file is not compatible with jQuery mobile, so, I tried to load jQuery 1.6.4.js and above versions. With these latest versions, the `getJSON` method is not working.

To be more specific, if I load:

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the code works fine, but when I load:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
```

it doesn't work...

I also tried it with the `$.ajax` method, but neither this is working.

Answer (score 0):

The main issues to Upgrading jQuery – from 1.4.x to 1.6.x:

- prop() and attr()
- Ajax and parseJSON
- getAttribute on Flash objects
- Plugins

I think [this link](http://www.davidtong.me/upgrading-jquery-from-1-4-x-to-1-6-1/) will help you.